# What does "ready to rock n' roll" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, colloquial-language

The sentence is from [*Eric Thomas’ Secrets to Success Speech*](http://www.lifesuccessquotes.com/33-motivational-quotes-from-eric-thomas-secrets-to-success-speech/).

> Guru said,
>   “If you wanna make money,
>   I’ll meet you tomorrow. 4 AM.”
>
> So the young man got there 4 AM.
>   **He all ready to rock n’ roll.**
>   Got on a suit.
>   Should have worn shorts.

Thanks

Comment: Citations need context, the man is not about to go out dancing, it's a figure of speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression that means, ready to move, to start doing something. The expression refers to the  dancing performed to rock n' roll music , with exaggerated body movements stressing the beat.

***[Let's rock and roll](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Let's+rock+and+roll!)!***

> - Inf. Let's get started!; Let's get moving!
>
>   - *A: Everybody ready? B: Yeah. A: Good. Let's rock and roll*!

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.